# Would like navbar not to move when minimizing browser window

Tags: css, navbar, nav

I've gotten my navbar to work like I wanted, mostly, but now, again, I am having the problem, that when I minimize the window, the navbar with all its links collapses, and it almost looks quite decent, but it covers over my content area and some of the link text runs over the navbar area and I have to hide that and etc. So the simplest way I thought was to have navbar not move at all, and just **be scrollable with the entire page**.

[image: not a busy cat](![not a busy cat]

Here is my CSS:

```
    #navBar{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
 left: 0;
}

#navBar ul{
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 65px;
 list-style:none;
 min-width:760px;
}

#navBar li{
 float: left;
 height: 65px;
}

#navBar li a:link , a:visited{
 font-size: 90%;
 display: block;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 20px 25px;
 font: 18px "open sans", sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar li a:hover{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
 <nav>
   <div id="navBar">
    <ul> 
     <li><a href="esileht.html">ESILEHT</a></li>
     <li><a href="uudised.html">UUDISED</a></li>
     <li><a href="ülevaated.html">ÜLEVAATED/ARVUSTUSED</a></li>
     <li><a href="login.html" id="logimine">LOGI SISSE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="content">
  <div id="logo">
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y4g5MOM.png" alt="Gaming website logo" height="84" width="540"/>
  </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="artikkel">
  <p>check check</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate some help, my first real webpage that I am working on, been trying quite a few things, but cannot seem to find a compromise, always one thing works and then the other thing wont work as intended..

Comment: did my answer fullfill your requirements or do you need more help? If you issue is sovleved, please tick my answer as accepted on the left top of it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `position:absolute;` and `float:left;` on `#navBar` like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8cBY2/1/)**

CSS :

```
#navBar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#navBar ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 65px;
    list-style:none;
}
#navBar li {
    float: left;
    height: 65px;
}
#navBar li a:link, a:visited {
    font-size: 90%;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    font: 18px"open sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navBar li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that it still collapses down on itself.

Comment: Also, if you want to make it stay at the top even when scrolling, add    position: fixed;

Comment: @Mike yes but it doesn't overlap the site content anymore and pushes it down when you reduce the window size

Comment: Ahh okay, I see where you are going... I was fixated on the fact that he didn't want it to collapse at all.

Comment: @Mike If you realy don't want it to move you can add `min-width` to the `<ul>` like this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8cBY2/4/

Comment: My css was a bit old, changed it, sorry. Now the navbar scrolls down with the  page, that I like, but when making the suggested changes, that feature dissapears, any way to find a compromise? Also in the long run I would like to get "LOGI SISSE" to the left side, I think that will also mess with minimizing the page.

Comment: @web-tiki not quite, if you check my css in a full sized browser page, you can see, that the navbar scrolls down, when u scroll down the page, like this website: http://www.continue-play.com/ . But when using suggestion above, that stops working.

Comment: @user3086917 ok I understand so this is what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s8AcJ/11/

Comment: @web-tiki sorry for bothering you so much, but now when I scroll to right at the bottom, the navbar wont scroll, like this: http://i.imgur.com/euzhJbW.jpg , maybe I did something wrong?